# Stepped search algorithm. Select one out of N, repeat, repeat, see end result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, search

I want to know how to think of search systems that require you make certain selections to see the end results. I am speaking about the `select` forms, where you proceed according to what you chose, and then you see your result.

One random example of what I'm talking is is described below. Imagine

```
Initial select  | Step 1         | Step 2                        | Step 3         | Step4    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A               | -- D or E or F | -- K or L or M or N           | -- RESULT      |
B               | -- D or H or I | -- O or P or L or Q or R      | -- RESULT      |
C               | -- D or I or J | -- Q or R or L or S or U or V | -- W or X or W | -- RESULT
```

Initial select being a `select` form in the beginning, and giving you more and more relevant `select`-s as you proceed, finally giving you an end result.

How are forms like these made? How should I organize data for this in SQL?

I can work with PHP, Ruby, JavaScript, SQL, NoSQL, HTML5/CSS. Please give me a an instruction, a link for a reading or something that will make me able to do such thing efficiently.

**Update**

*Maybe you could tell me the name of such system so I can research myself. What should I call such search for Google to understand me?*

Comment: Decision tree, perhaps? There's a little too much abstracted away here.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the options by way of self-referencing foreign key, e.g.:

```
create table decisions(
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  parent_id int unsigned,
  primary key (id),
  constraint fk_decisions_parent_id foreign key (parent_id) references decisions (id)
    on delete cascade on update cascade
)engine=innodb;
```

To find the options based on a decision, you would then query as follows:

```
 select *
 from decisions
 where parent_id = [decision ID];
```

If no options are returned, then you have arrived at your "RESULT".